# How to detemine learning rate during training neural network?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

If I want to use manual learning rate, for example, initial learning rate is 0.01, after 10000 steps, decay learning rate to 0.001, and after 20000 steps, decay learning rate to 0.0001.

How can I know these steps I need to decay learning rate? Is there any experience can guide me?

We usually can find these steps in paper, but how does author get these steps?

Answer (score 1):

A good initial learning rate is one that is as high as possible without causing the error to diverge. This is found by trial and error. Guess some typical initial learning rate like 0.01, run a few epochs and see what happens. If the error is diverging then divide by 10, otherwise multiply by 10. Settle on the highest value before you run into divergent error.

A good time to lower the learning rate is when you notice the error does not seem to be improving anymore. For example you run 100 epochs at lr=0.01 and the error is plateauing. Try reducing your learning rate to 0.001.

You can also consider using [learning rate decay](https://towardsdatascience.com/learning-rate-schedules-and-adaptive-learning-rate-methods-for-deep-learning-2c8f433990d1) where you set a schedule to decay the learning rate automatically.

Comment: When I train the `cnn`, I find something strange. After some steps, training-set loss becomes less than validation-set loss, is this mean I need to decay learning rate?

Comment: You are probably overfitting the training data. Try adding dropout or L2 regularization.

Comment: I have used L2 regularization and batch normalization.

Comment: Try increasing the L2 penalty? For a `CNN` you could try using [data augmentation](https://medium.com/ymedialabs-innovation/data-augmentation-techniques-in-cnn-using-tensorflow-371ae43d5be9) to generate more training data. You can also try a simpler architecture.

Comment: I have used data augmentation and use resnet architecture for object detection on pascal voc 2007, which pretrained on imagenet. The architecture likes `yolo`, but I find using manual learning rate, initial rate is 0.01, after 4K steps, the training loss begins to be less than validation loss.  And the learning don't decay, the model is overfitting. So I wonder whether I should decay learning rate before 4K steps.

Comment: I don't think adjusting the learning rate will help with overfitting. Overfitting happens when your network learns to "memorize" specific training examples instead of properly generalizing. Regularization techniques try and mitigate the network's ability to memorize individual training examples, for example by forcing it to learn a sparser representation which is more likely to generalize. Using a different strategy to adjust the learning rate is not likely to help with overfitting, because this does not really affect anything related to the network's ability to overfit.

Comment: Training error a little lower than validation error is not unusual. You should only be concerned when there is a big discrepancy. If this is the case then the best you can do is to try harder with your regularization efforts. Maybe you didn't quite choose the right hyperparameters, or maybe you have a bug.

Comment: For me, I can't get high MAP as `yolo` of paper. The MAP of validation-set is lower than training-set. I also try some hyperparameters, but failed. Maybe there is a bug in my code, but I think it's difficult to find the bug. So do you have any experience to help to adjust paramters of neural network?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160797/discussion-between-imran-and-gaussclb).